# custom button onDraw setBackgroundColor

Tags: android

I subclassed Button in order to display custom background color on the button.

I just need to display a square filled with green or red wether the connection to the server is established or not.

I chose the View to be a Button because i wanted to re-draw the color onClick.

Having this code ran the custom Button's background color is always the first color that is set.

I logged multiple places in the app and I don't know why it's not doing what I want.

The `ConnectionButtonView.invalidate()` is called whenever the connection state changes. I logged that and I get the correct output: the `Log.d("conn", ""+activity.isWAMPConnected());` prints the right status of the connection right after the connection state changes.

I would like to delete this class, if it is possible to change the background of a Button (View) programatically. So far I wasn't able to do this.

```
public class ConnectionButtonView extends Button {
    FullscreenActivity activity;
    public ConnectionButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        activity = (FullscreenActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int color;
        Log.d("conn", ""+activity.isWAMPConnected());
        if(activity.isWAMPConnected())
            color = 0xFF00FF00;
        else
            color = 0xFFFF0000;
        setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Update: some log

```
D/conn﹕ true
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader﹕ created
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader﹕ created
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader﹕ running
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection﹕ reader created and started
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter﹕ created
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnWriter﹕ created
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection﹕ writer created and started
D/conn﹕ true
D/conn﹕ true
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9128K, 36% free 33777K/52496K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection﹕ opening handshake received
D/wamp﹕ connected to ws://86.127.137.166:2014/pubsub
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader﹕ invalid WAMP message: missing array close or invalid additional args
D/conn﹕ true
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection﹕ WAMP session 539a38de65f7c established
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader﹕ run() : ConnectionLost
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader﹕ ended
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection﹕ fail connection [code = 3, reason = WebSockets connection lost
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader﹕ quit
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter﹕ ended
D/wamp﹕ disconnected from ws://86.127.137.166:2014/pubsub
D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection﹕ worker threads stopped
D/conn﹕ false
D/conn﹕ false
```

Update:
After changing the context from the containing view and back to it, the background color is ok.
Still why and how?

Comment: Do you set an onClick method when you make the button? Does your onClick method tell the button to re-draw itself?

Comment: No. The ConnectionButtonView.invalidate() is called whenever the connection state changes.

Answer (score 0):

try `setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#FF00FF00"))` or `setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#FFFF0000"))` instead, I think your problem is the integers.

Also, you should be able to do that from outside the class, there is probably no need to extend a button.

Comment: why should be that? if the activity.isWAMPConnected() returns true when this view is first drawn the background is green, else it's red

Comment: so why not just say if (isWAMPConnected()) setBackgroundColor(connectedColor) else setBackgroundColor(notConnectedColor), you should be able to do that from the activity

Answer (score 0):

**Why it doesn't work:** `super.onDraw()` is what actually draws the button, including its background. If you don't call it, `setBackgroundColor()` will have no effect. Be careful though, since `setBackgroundColor()` calls `invalidate()` itself, which will probably cause a stack overflow.

I think changing the background from outside the class when the state changes is a much better idea. If you have a method called when this happens (and you apparently have, since you're calling `invalidate()`, then just change the background there.

In short, wherever you have this code:

```
myButton.invalidate();
```

just swap by:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(isWAMPConnected() ? color1 : color2);
```

And make `myButton` a standard `Button` widget instead of your custom class.

Comment: Actually I don't know if this is true: "setBackgroundColor() calls invalidate()" because I don't get any error and the application works.
Calling the super.onDraw() makes no difference :'(

Comment: It might do so, depending on the changes (e.g. it might not if changing one color by another). Check the source for `View.setBackgroundDrawable()` which is called by it. So at the very least it's unsafe.

Comment: @AdrianMunteanu I tried to explain myself better. This seems like an easier (and much safer) alternative.

Comment: I firstly tried that and it didn't work. Can the problem be that i try to setBackgroundColor of a View in an onSomething?

also, check this out:
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        if (mBackground instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ((ColorDrawable) mBackground.mutate()).setColor(color);
            computeOpaqueFlags();
            mBackgroundResource = 0;
        } else {
            setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
        }
    }

Comment: That's precisely what I meant when I said that _changing one color by another_ might not call invalidate(). But setBackground(Drawable) can, for example if there wasn't a color previously. :)

Comment: @AdrianMunteanu Maybe you could explain exactly what problem you were having with the other solution?

Comment: I used your idea. I tested more. The background is the one that I set in XML, BUT it changes after I go to other contentView and back. Also, it changes only if after coming back the background gets set. This is >.<

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create a subclass to do this. Button inherits from View which has the method setBackgroundColor(int color), so you should just be able to call this method from your Activity at the appropriate place.
You can see the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Here is an example function that you can call:

```
 //setup your button from its layout in xml
 private Button button;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate();

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
     }

//change its color if it is connected or not
private void checkWAMP(){

 if(activity.isWAMPConnected()){
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
 else{
   button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }

}
```

Comment: How about it does not want to work? :'( setBackgroundColor does nothing as far as I can see

Comment: That's strange huh. Are you just using a standard button? Is it linking properly with the button specified in your layout xml (try change the text programatically)? Also, test by manually invalidating it after changed. Another method that I have used before with success is `button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.your_resource_defined_color);`
To use that method you need to define your color in the color resource file.

Comment: I am pretty sure I get the button with findViewById because with toString it prints the id that i set to it. I have tried button.invalidate() and still no result. It seems the only way is to go to other contentView and back again, and it will work exactly as I want.

Comment: Your right, it should probably invalidate itself when it's set. It might be useful to see what your Activity code looks like, just to rule out any problems there, because I'm not quite sure what you mean by going to the other contentView.

Comment: I meant that I tap some other button, the activity calls setContentView(someOtherView), then I press back, onBackPressed calls setContentView(home), then the background changes every time the setBackgroundColor is called

Comment: Again, I think it would be quite useful to see your Activity code. Changing the contentView twice within an Activity doesn't sound the best (or standard way) of doing things (in my opinion). There may be a better way. Changing the contentView again could override any UI changes you have made before you did that.

Comment: If you don't mind, please check out https://github.com/realtimedraw/realtimedraw_android/tree/alpha